# Viewing Proposed Changes As Raw Text When Revieweing

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Sometimes it would be better to review changes based on the raw text instead of the formatted text.

Example: Someone puts some XML code into the text, which disappears in the resulting formatted text. Someone else proposes to format the XML as code. As a reviewer I can't see if the change only makes invisible text visible or if the author actually changed or added the text. I may go to the post and open it in the editor to see the original raw text - which is cumbersome.

So it would be nice to have a raw view for reviewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already do this:

[image: Showing raw text suggested edit]

While it may not be entirely clear (the icon isn't very suggestive, and the text isn't monospace like you get in the normal 'view source' or edit areas), the second button on the left shows the raw version of the edit.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this. I should change the feature request to "make the feature more visible" :-)